# how to inject by keys pair value using lodash in node js

Tags: json, node.js, lodash

My jsob object look like this

```
{"LAB_123":{"abc":"bde"},"LAB_345":{"abc":"efg"}}
```

Second json object is

```
{"LAB_123":{"xyz":"dfe"},"LAB_345":{"PQR":"ABC"}}
```

I need to join those two object to create one json array which should look like this

```
{"LAB_123":{"abc":"bde","xyz":"dfe"},"LAB_345":{"abc":"efg","PQR":"ABC"}}
```

I can add keys values using looping through the json array but is there any method using lodash which will make this code look easier.

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge

Answer (score 2):

You can use lodash's [`_.merge()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge), which recursively merges the object. Since merge mutates the 1st object (the 1st param), use an empty object to avoid mutating the original objects:

```js
const a = {"LAB_123":{"abc":"bde"},"LAB_345":{"abc":"efg"}};

const b = {"LAB_123":{"xyz":"dfe"},"LAB_345":{"PQR":"ABC"}};

const result = _.merge({}, a, b);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you want an array of objects, you can split the result of the 1st example using [`_.toPairs()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#toPairs) to key/value pairs, and map them to objects:

```js
const a = {"LAB_123":{"abc":"bde"},"LAB_345":{"abc":"efg"}};

const b = {"LAB_123":{"xyz":"dfe"},"LAB_345":{"PQR":"ABC"}};

const result = _({})
  .merge(a, b)
  .toPairs()
  .map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }))
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```